# NSAttributedString initWithHTML incorrect character encoding?

Tags: cocoa, nsattributedstring

`-[NSMutableAttributedString initWithHTML:documentAttributes:]` seems to mangle special characters:

```
NSString *html = @"“Hello” World"; // notice the smart quotes
NSData *htmlData = [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableAttributedString *as = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:htmlData documentAttributes:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", as);
```

That prints `â€œHelloâ€ World` followed by some RTF commands. In my application, I convert the attributed string to RTF and display it in an `NSTextView`, but the characters are corrupted there, too.

According to the documentation, the default encoding is UTF-8, but I tried being explicit and the result is the same:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]};
NSMutableAttributedString *as = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:htmlData documentAttributes:&attributes];
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use `[html dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]` when creating the NSData and set the matching encoding option when you parse the HTML into an attributed string:

The documentation for `NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute` is slightly confusing:

> NSNumber, containing an int specifying the `NSStringEncoding` for the
>   file; for reading and writing plain text files and writing HTML;
>   default for plain text is the default encoding; default for HTML is
>   UTF-8.

So, you code should be:

```
NSString *html = @"“Hello” World";
NSData *htmlData = [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *options = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                    NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)};
NSMutableAttributedString *as =
    [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:htmlData
                                            options: options
                                 documentAttributes:nil];
```

Comment: You should try the other answer first in case they're right about my answer only working accidentally. I haven't had a chance to test it myself. :-X

Comment: They are partially right. This is the same answer (more or less) and it works. I made this answer clearer since it is marked as correct.

Comment: really useful for me, just add the NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute, then it show ok

Answer (score 13):

Swift version of accepted answer is:

```
let htmlString: String = "Hello world contains html</br>"
let data: Data = Data(htmlString.utf8)

let options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey: Any] = [
    .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
]

let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data,
    options: options,
    documentAttributes: nil)
```

Answer (score 11):

The previous answer here works, but mostly by accident.

Making an `NSData` with `NSUnicodeStringEncoding` will tend to work, because that constant is an alias for `NSUTF16StringEncoding`, and UTF-16 is pretty easy for the system to identify.  Easier than UTF-8, which apparently was being identified as some other superset of ASCII (it looks like `NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding` in your case, probably because it's one of the few ASCII-based encodings with mappings for 0x8_ and 0x9_).

That answer is mistaken in quoting the documentation for `NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute`, because "attributes" are what you get *out* of `-initWithHTML`.  That's why it's `NSDictionary **` and not just `NSDictionary *`.  You can pass in a pointer to an `NSDictionary *`, and you'll get out keys like TopMargin/BottomMargin/LeftMargin/RightMargin, PaperSize, DocumentType, UTI, etc.  Any values you try to pass *in* through the "attributes" dictionary are ignored.

You need to use "options" for passing values *in*, and the relevant option key is `NSTextEncodingNameDocumentOption`, which has no documented default value.  It's passing the bytes to WebKit for parsing, so if you don't specify an encoding, presumably you're getting WebKit's encoding-guessing heuristics.

To guarantee the encoding types match between your `NSData` and `NSAttributedString`, what you should do is something like:

```
NSString *html = @"“Hello” World";
NSData *htmlData = [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableAttributedString *as =
    [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:htmlData
                                            options:@{NSTextEncodingNameDocumentOption: @"UTF-8"}
                                 documentAttributes:nil];
```

Comment: I don't think that is what the other answer was suggesting. It just wasn't complete.

Comment: Actually, this os the correct answer. The other answer really does only work if `-initWithHTML` by chance detects the right encoding. Using the `options`is the right way to go. Thanks!