# NSAttributedString not working for UILabel after using HTML code

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I have UILabel and I am assigning html text as below.

```
m014.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style type='text/css'>body {background-color: transparent;border: 0px;margin: 0px;padding: 0px;font-family: '%@'; font-size: %fpx;;ccolor:;}</style></head><body dir='%@'>%@<style type='text/css'> iframe { width: 100%% !important; } img {width: 100%% !important; height: auto;} table {width: 100%%;}</style></body></html>", localize(@"myFontName"), @16, localize(@"myDir"), m014.text];

m014.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData: [m014.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding] options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes: nil error: nil];
```

In iOS 10 & below I can see normal text (plain text) however in iOS 11 & above I see html text in the app. I see html code as it is...

Any idea why this is happening?

---

Majorly, I feel problem is in below line.

```
[m014.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding]
```

But I remember, I used `NSUTF32StringEncoding` because I was seeing encoded characters.

Comment: 1. Why not use `initWithHTML:documentAttributes:` and 2. Try using `NSUTF8StringEncoding`

Comment: @rmaddy : Point 1 tell me my mistake (I believe)... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy) for an answer in comment.

Update code I used is as below.

```
m014.attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:
    [m014.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] 
    options: @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, 
    NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} 
    documentAttributes:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try NSUTF8StringEncoding when converting a HTML string to NSAttributtedString?

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[yourHTMLString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] 
                                 options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                           NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} 
                      documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

Comment: yes and I had issues, so went ahead with NSUTF32StringEncoding

Comment: What issues did you have?

Comment: I tried with this NSString and it worked. [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style type='text/css'>body {background-color: transparent;border: 0px;margin: 0px;padding: 0px; font-size: 16px;;ccolor:;}</style></head><body >%@<style type='text/css'> iframe { width: 100%% !important; } img {width: 100%% !important; height: auto;} table {width: 100%%;}</style></body></html>", _labelView.text];

Can you explain what issue you had?

Comment: did you try with arabic texT? & iOS 11?

Comment: I tried with English. I will try with arabic and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using similar code in my app, but use `NSUTF16StringEncoding`, following the hints in some other answers, like this: [NSAttributedString initWithHTML incorrect character encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956698).